# QT Webview url loading

Tags: qt

Mine is a somple application,I am just loading a url page(loading from server) in the widget window.

Ex:

```
QWebView->load(QUrl("xxxxx"));
QWebView->show();
```

this url contains some jpeg image and javascript.

The problem here is my application is able to page correctly in some machines but in some machines jpeg image is not able to load.

Please help me to resolve this issue. I am just surprised what could be the reason.

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with an SDK build of Qt, the ability to view JPEGs in a Qt application is based on the JPEG plugin.

Please see one of the following links:

- http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/deployment.html
- http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/deployment-plugins.html

Alternatively, if you are building from source, you can compile JPEG support into Qt itself.

Comment: thnaks clare macrae..it helped me to write my application a lot.